# invalid literal for int() with base 10 Django with valid integer timestamp

Tags: python, django

I have a charting library which requires my data in the epoch/Unix timestamp timestamp.

So I convert it like this:

```
    ydm = 20170101
    ymd = ms['dimensions'][0] + '-' + '235959'
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(ymd,'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
    date = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    ts = int(d.strftime("%s")) * 1000
```

This works fine and as a result I get a human readable field `2017-04-08` and I timestamp `1491695999000`

I'm trying to save both fields in my db, I first tried with a `IntegerField`, but I was getting the above error, I thought that it was because of the timestamp being such a big number so I also tried a `BigIntegerField` but I keep getting the error with a random(?) number near like: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100.0'` The number has always a dot and I guess that's why django rightly is not accepting it.

My view looks something like this:

```
    print('time stamp is: '+str(ts)) # This is an int and the result is something like this: `time stamp is: 1491868799000`

    # Save Metrics to DB
    gp = GoogleProperty.objects.get(google_email=current_user)
    user_id = int(gp.user_id)
    property_id = gp.property_id
    property_name = gp.property_name
    obj, created = GaCountries.objects.get_or_create(property_id=property_id, date=date, country=country,
                                                defaults={
                                                            'owner':user_id,
                                                            'property_id':property_id,
                                                            'date':date,
                                                            'property_name':property_name, # Remove Later
                                                            'country':country,
                                                            'sessions' : sessions,
                                                            'users' : users,
                                                            'pageviews' : pageviews,
                                                            'bouncerate': bouncerate,
                                                            'timestamp' : ts,
                                                            })
    if not created: # If exists which data should be replaced:
         obj.date = date 
         ---ETC
```

The problem occurs in the line: `'timestamp' : ts,` but I'm sure ts is an integer and the data is correct.

The model now is:

```
timestamp = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

But I tried also with other types of fields...

Any ideas?

Comment: `'100.0'` is so way off from any current timestamp, that my guess would be that one of the other values is to blame and not the timestamp.

Comment: Oh... this would make much sense, but when django debug highlights a line like in here: (https://snag.gy/TySRAc.jpg) doesn't that mean that the error is in that line?

Comment: For multiline-statements, the line print of the stacktrace is off in Python. If you make `'bouncerate': bouncerate` last in the dictionary literal, you'll get that line printed.

Comment: Oh this solves everything. Thanks